# React: Conditional rendering CSS classes with Animate on Scroll library

Tags: css, reactjs, class, ternary, conditional-rendering

I'm using the Animate on Scroll library and React-Bootstrap for a project. Using the following code applies the animation:

```
      <Row>
        <Col xs={{span: 12}} 
             md={{span: 8, offset: 2}}                               
             data-aos="fade-right">
          <H2>Header</H2>
          <P>
            paragraph content
          </P>
        </Col>
      </Row>
```

`data-aos="fade-right"` properly applies the animation. However, I only want the animation to be applied with the user is viewing the site on desktop. I'm familiar with media queries, but I'm unsure how to apply this `data-aos="fade-right"` so that it is only applied on desktops and not tablets or mobile.

Can I use React's conditional rendering to only apply `data-aos="fade-right"` when the browser width is 786px+?

How can I grab the width of the browser, ensure that it is 768px or greater, and then apply `data-ose="fade-right"` to the Bootstrap Col so that the animation only runs on large screens?

I've tried using window.innerWidth in a ternary operator but have some errors:

```
      <Row>
        <Col xs={{span: 12}}
             md={{span: 8, offset: 2}}
             {`${window.innerWidth > '700px' ? "data-aos="fade-right"" : ""}`}>
          <H2>Header</H2>
          <P>
            paragraph content
          </P>
        </Col>
      </Row>
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the code with a div tag with

```
   <div style={{ /*your media queries */ }} ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your content with a wrapper like `div` and then use conditional rendering,

Condition,

```
const showAnimation = window.innerWidth > 700
```

Usage

```
<Row>
   <Col xs={{span: 12}} md={{span: 8, offset: 2}}>
     {showAnimation ? (
        <div className="aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right">
          <h2>Header</h2>
          <p>paragraph content</p>
        </div>
     ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>Header</h2>
          <p>paragraph content</p>
        </div>
     )}
   </Col>
</Row>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-7vnpw?fontsize=14)

Comment: When using Demo link above try to adjust output part width.

Answer (score 0):

`const showAnimation = window.innerWidth > 700

data-aos={showAnimation ?"": "fade-in"}`